# Perl MIME::Lite sending empty Excel file

Tags: linux, excel, perl

I am creating an excel file in perl using Spreadsheet::WriteExcel. My code starts like this

```
my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('map.xls');
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet('map');
```

adds some data to workSheet

and then

```
$workbook->close() or die "Error closing file: $!";
```

but the excel file I get contains just one row with an error message

[image]
My MIME attachment code is like this

```
$msg->attach(
Type        => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
Path        => $sNoticeFile,
Disposition => "attachment",
);
```

can someone please tell me what is missing/wrong in the code? Thank you

Comment: Obligatory FYI...the `MIME::Lite` [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Lite#WAIT) say: "**WAIT!** MIME::Lite is not recommended by its current maintainer. There are a number of alternatives, like Email::MIME or MIME::Entity and Email::Sender, which you should probably use instead. MIME::Lite continues to accrue weird bug reports, and it is not receiving a large amount of refactoring due to the availability of better alternatives. Please consider using something else."

Comment: Sorry, I get a similar result from MIME::Entity . I tried that.

Comment: I'm not saying it's the source of your problem, just that you probably shouldn't use it.

Comment: How do you create `$sNoticeFile`? What's its content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. My row counter was not incrementing at the right place. It was always writing new data from the database to row number 2.

Thank everyone.